# Python readlines() returns empty string

Tags: python, readfile

I ran the following code in Python:

```
def translateDesc(fileName):
    textFile = open("fileName", "r")
    fileLines = textFile.readlines()
    return fileLines
```

And the function returns an empty string. However, when I ran the lines one by one in the iPython terminals, the function returned was not empty. How should I fix this issue?

Comment: Use the `filename` variable: `textFile = open(fileName, "r")`

Comment: And be more clear. `readlines` doesn't return strings. It returns a list of some number of strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please replace 2nd line with below:
textFile = open(fileName, "r")

#we need to use the variable name in line 2 instead of string "fileName".

Answer (score 1):

`readlines()` returns a list of strings.If you want to return string use `read()`

```
def translateDesc(fileName):
    textFile = open(fileName, "r")
    fileLines = textFile.read()
    return fileLines
```